Need help identifying resistor
According to my colour-blindness-free wife, this is: red, orange, yellow, black.

Which, according to https://resistorcolorcodecalc.com/ works out at 230 kΩ.
However, that's not what the meter shows:

Could anyone help identify the correct resistance, please?
This is taken out of my bathroom ventilator fan, it had a cold joint and burned the board a little. There is "R5" printed beside it:


The value looks inconsistent with any possible color combination it could be interpreted as..

the first two bands look the same ... orange, orange, yellow, gold ... or red, red, yellow, gold .... maybe it's a faded red, red, orange, gold

@jsotola o,o,y,g or r,r,y,g - that's four colours. Now, I know i'm the colour-blind here, but i am quite sure there are only 3 colured rings followed by 1 black ring on that thing, would you agree?

Did some toying around with the image's brightness/contrast/gamma. It seems to be orange more often than red in these adjustments but this isn't necessarily proof that it is indeed orange. Either way, your multimeter's reading is way off from the resistor's intended ohmage. Perhaps what you can do is measure the current draw at that gap and maybe you can size a resistor based on that.

thanks Eugene Sh. & Colin, here's a better photo - https://imgur.com/kITogbO - wife says it's definitely red, orange, yellow so the meter reading must indeed be wrong, perhaps because the resistor suffered damage when it got burned. I think my neighbour has the same ventilator fan installed, i might pop over with a meter one day

I guess it could be a 22k and the colors have just aged poorly from the heat, but the resistance is still within tolerance (well, maybe not quite, but maybe it was 10%, it's not unheard of). But for an accurate answer, dunno -- if someone recognizes the exact type (preferably make and model) and knows how they age at temp, that might be a (IMHO) sufficient answer.

as the scorched circuit board was not caused by the resistor itself, but instead by the cold joint, 22K (like it is close to now) is probably correct.

The fourth band being seen as either gold or black could be the same phenomenon observed with "The dress".
